# How to pass the current context to include in Twig?

Tags: twig

Say I have the following `headline.twig` partial:

```
<h2>{{ headline }}</h2>
```

and I want to include it in two places, once as:

```
<% for article in teasers %>
  {{ include('headline.twig') }}
<% endfor %>
```

And then simply:

```
{{ include('headline.twig') }}
```

Is it possible to pass an `include` tag or function its context, so that the include "knows" that in the first instance the `headline` variable is actually `article.headline`?

I'm looking for a systematic way to do this, not with something like

```
{{ include('headline.twig', {headline: article.headline}) }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `headline` to be in the main context of your included file in all cases, you can do something like this:

```
{% for article in teasers %}
  {% set headline = article.headline %}
  {{ include('headline.twig') }}
{% endfor %}
```

But this will overwrite any existing `headline` variable in your current context if you're re-setting it this way (and risk to repeat 2 times the last iteration of `teasers.article.headline`).

The best solution if you want to keep your current context AND overwrite `headline` variable is to use the [`merge`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/merge.html) filter:

```
{% for article in teasers %}
  {{ include('headline.twig', _context|merge({headline: article.headline})) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a simpler solution than the merge filter (which could get pretty clumsy sometimes), but I guess there just isn't one

Answer (score 1):

By default whole context is passed to included template.

So it will work in `headline.twig`:

```
<h2>{{ article.headline }}</h2>
```

And then in main template you only call:

```
{% include('headline.twig') %}
```

But `article` variable must be defined in moment of calling `include`.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really solve the issue for me. Your suggestion is pretty much like doing `{{ include('headline.twig', {headline: article.headline}) }}`,  just in the opposite direction